# Access token implementaion in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook, wcf, asmx, access-token

How to use *access-token* concept that is used in facebook.

1)Can we implement same concept in ASP.NET  based web application?

2)Can we use this concept in adding security to access in webservice *ASMX* and *WCF* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time I have found the answer I have posted.
If I am wrong please review my answer.
1) In Facebook server flow authentication when user is successfully authenticated **Facebook generates authorization code parameter name as** *code*.

2)In second step using all this parameter *authorization code* with *client* _ *secret* ,*client* _ *id* , *redirect* _ *uri* , *state*  call Webrequest  or call service  if success then response have two parameter *accessToken* ,*expires* _ *in*.

3) This *accessToken* is used  for getting userinfo like firstname,lastname,birthday etc with specified *scope*.

And this is general scenario that is used with WCF and ASMX webservice by storing valid accessToken to safe place or further use.

Answer (score 0):

1) Access token is just a hash from some parameters, e.g.:

```
MD5(userName, userMail, someSalt, someOtherStuff)
```

So you can implement it for sure the way you like it. But better if it contains some `secret` information that can be retrived only by current user

2) Yes you can. As social networks like facebook do it:

there's some application secret key that is known on a server side (where your service runs), and some signature that can be retrieved from facebook api for some app and user and some other information.

Your facebook app gets that signature, it can use it to make hashsum with other parameters like userLogin, application scores or w/e else. Sends it to server.

On a server side you generate signature same way as your appliaction do based on parameters. If signatures are same request is valid. If know - someone is trying to do dirty things :)

Comment: can we apply MD5 access token concept for asmx webservice as security feature.?

Comment: can you give me just process step for creating above? <br>like